# How can I recover files from a deleted NTFS partition?

Tags: data-recovery, ntfs

Suddenly I deleted my NTFS partition from the Disk in Ubuntu and later I created a new partition of the same name from the one I deleted before. 
Now I have some files in there I'm missing.

I want to retrieve my data before formatting this partition. What can I do to achieve this. I tested `Testdisk`, but it won't help.

Answer (score 0):

to recover data, you may try as follows:

Boot with your Ubuntu Live DVD/USB and open Terminal

1. `sudo fdisk -l` to find the exact partition number (sdaX/hdaX - where X is 1/2/3 etc.)
2. Then `sudo ntfsundelete /dev/sdaX` (or hdaX)
3. If ntfsundelete gives error, then `sudo apt-get install ntfsprogs`
4. Now ntfsundelete should work
5. To undelete a file, check the ntfsundelete report, you should see the files with a **Inode** number at the left
6. `sudo ntfsundelete /dev/sdaX –u –i <Inode>` (or hdaX)
7. Your files should now be recovered, but you can only see them as a Root user
8. Change the files ownership to normal user `sudo chown ubuntu <Files>`

Hope this helps

Comment: This won't help at all since the original partition has been partially overwritten.